# .Net Core 5 WebApp : How to invalidate concurrent login

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I understand that a WebApp is stateless. Also understand that a user might simply close the browser and we will have to wait until they come back and login again! We can logout a user only when they click logout or let the session expire.

I did create a custom table where I log a record for a new login and close that record on logout. I remove the previous unclosed records for same user on login.

My requirements are

1. Allow users to stay logged in for 1 hour from same machine. I have setup SlidingExpiration=true.
2. How do I prevent the user from logging in from another machine.

I figured out that somehow I need to store "a handle" of a logged in user in a table. When same user logs in, logout other "handles".

I saw this [link](https://tech.trailmax.info/2015/09/prevent-multiple-logins-in-asp-net-identity/) which does that, but they are using Cookie-based-authentication, but I have built entirely using Identity.

Any pointers?
Here is a snippet from my Startup for reference...

```
        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(options =>
        {
            options.Lockout.AllowedForNewUsers = true;
            options.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(1);
            options.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 5;
            options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true;
            options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false;
            options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedPhoneNumber = false;
            options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
        }).AddEntityFrameworkStores<MyDBContext>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        services.Configure<DataProtectionTokenProviderOptions>(opt => opt.TokenLifespan = TimeSpan.FromHours(2));

        services.AddScoped<IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<ApplicationUser>, AppClaimsPrincipalFactory>();


        services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
        {
            // Password settings.
            options.Password.RequireDigit = true;
            options.Password.RequireLowercase = true;
            options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = true;
            options.Password.RequireUppercase = true;
            options.Password.RequiredLength = 6;
            options.Password.RequiredUniqueChars = 1;

            // User settings.
            options.User.AllowedUserNameCharacters =
            "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789-._@";
            options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = false;
        });
        services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
        {
            // Cookie settings
            options.Cookie.Name = "TTSessionCookie";
            options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
            options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60);
            options.LoginPath = "/Identity/Account/Login";
            options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Identity/Account/AccessDenied";
            options.SlidingExpiration = true;
        });

        services.AddMvc().AddSessionStateTempDataProvider().AddRazorPagesOptions(opt=>opt.Conventions.AuthorizePage("/Account/Login"));
        services.AddAntiforgery(a => a.HeaderName = "XAF-TOKEN");
        services.AddSession();
        services.AddRazorPages();
```

Comment: Can you track it by session id.? When session is enabled server will create unique session id and store it in cookie. For each subsequent request server will receive same session id. You can check if session id is different then log out user.

Comment: Sure. But each of the subsequent request is via different page and without having to place authentication code in each page, is there a simpler way to validate that?

Comment: From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-6.0 `Empty sessions aren't retained. The session must have at least one value set to persist the session across requests. When a session isn't retained, a new session ID is generated for each new request.`  So you may have to create at least  one value inside session so server can receive same session id

Comment: My issue is not session retention.
Scenario:
User A is using Machine A and logs in.  - Lets call it SessionA1
I created an entry into my CustomSession table and also added an unique session variable

Immediately (or within 1 hrs) User A uses Machine B to login. Lets call this Session2A
From my CustomSession table, I know there is an active login.
At this point, if I can have a handle of SessionA1 in my local table, then I can invalidate that login and allow this one to continue. 

Now Session1A will be invalid and if user tries another login then Session2A will also be invalid.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of trial-error, I managed to solve this by using Middleware!

1. Setup middleware to read a custom Session variable
2. During login set the session variable and store in a db.
3. app.UseMiddleware() will ensure each call gets routed here. If the custom Session variable value doesnt match the latest login, logout the user and send them to Login page!
   Voila! User can use their login only in 1 browser/session. Their latest wins always. They can keep doing ping-pong-login only to realize soon - the system wont let them do dual session.